# Cost of moving and hiding/showing google map's div

Tags: jquery, google-maps, backbone.js

My application is a single page app (backbone.js) and it uses google maps that is stored inside a `#map_canvas` div.

The application has 3 main views:

- A google map view.
- A view without the map. (ie the `#map_canvas` get hidden)
- A view with the map in a subdiv. (I append the `#map_canvas` div to another div)

So basically I have 3 main dom manipulations I do:

1. Hiding the map
2. Showing the map
3. Appending the map to another div

My question is, how costly are those operations?

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about performance doing this 3 operations as long as you don't do them like 10times/second...

Comment: No, I don't it 10times/second :) But isn't that dom manipulation costly? after all google map's canvas are huge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of money: free.

In terms of execution time: negligible

In terms of implementation time: very small (use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for cross browser dom manipulation)

Comment: Regarding execution time, how can you be so sure it's negligible? :)

Comment: Could you link to the project? and btw, yes of course i'm using jquery since i'm using backbone ;)

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a behind the firewall app.

Comment: You really don't have to worry about showing/hiding elements on page... You can do like thousands of hides and shows / second....

Comment: Okay! Thank you both for the feedback :)

Comment: actually.. it's to reduce page loads that i want to hide/show/move the map ;) I was afraid that the tradeof would be a hit on performance.

Comment: Put this in the javascript console here on stackoverflow: for(var i=0;i<=100; ++i) { $('div').hide(); $('div').show(); } . It hides and shows 100 times * 120divs each time, all in a few milliseconds...

Answer (score 2):

How costly they are? almost very negligible. I think you're not concerned about the hiding and showing since it's pretty much straightforward and the execution time of this is almost 0. But I think you're worried about relocation the div inside the DOM to append it to the other div. That shouldn't take time as well since the Maps API has already been loaded so moving it won't disturb the Maps API.

if you use jQuery then simply go ahead and do it, you shouldn't be worried since jQuery uses the fastest methods

If you want to append in another div for design purposes I would recommend that you write another css and load it instead of appending the div, that will instantly (when the css is loaded) change the design of the div you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about old browser compatibility use zeptojs instead of jQuery... might add a little bit of performance improvement... But honestly it's no big deal.

Comment: I'm using jqueryUI and twitter-bootstrap. I think both need jquery!